# Standard C library not working for some reason

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, virtual-machine, libraries, fedora

I have a bunch of libraries that do not seem to be able to be opened on my Fedora Workstation 38 virtual machine. It is a fresh install, and the system that the virtual machine is running on is Windows 10. I would assume that since a standard library for C is not functioning as it should(as the file I am having issues with is a .c file), I would need to reinstall the compiler or something. The IDE is Visual Studio Code, and it is also a fresh install(bar the C/C++ extension). I'm not sure if I need to upload the program that I was using, but I included a screenshot of my screen.
What should I do?
[image]

Comment: Have you installed a compiler?

Comment: I would assume that comes preinstalled with visual studio code. If not, how would I go about it?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). We especially do not need an image of your entire desktop in order to see a few error messages that can't be read.

Comment: "The IDE is Visual Studio Code" That's your problem right here, VSCode is a finicky IDE to set up, and is not recommended for beginners. Absolutely nothing comes preinstalled with it.

Comment: The message says "Please run the 'Select Intellisense Configuration´command to locate your system headers". Did you do that?

Comment: Also, the white dot next to the file name indicates that some edits to the source is not yet saved to disk. VS Code will then happily compile the old version instead!

Comment: VS Code ist not an IDE at all out of the box. It is a text editor can can be made doing some tricks to act like an IDE. All the IDE part needs to be added extra: Compiler, debugger, the extension to use the compiler and debugger, ... To some extent that is understandable, as you could use VSCode to do Python programming, Java programming or any other stuff where it would be just a waste of resources to put every compiler into a package. Furthermore, Microsoft does not have licences to distribute all possible compilers and interpreters.

Comment: This sounds like a FAQ. I haven't used the IDE but there's some json/xml/whatever file which you need to tweak and there should be plenty of answers elsewhere on SO about how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem some months ago and I just restarted fedora and then I moved my files to another place and back to where it was. You can also try to refresh/update your vscode. Check if fedora has no updates running. Most of the time this come from your IDE, if you're mostly doing C, I recommand you CLion.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).